# Not able to navigate on button click?

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, xaml, windows-phone-7

Following is my code.I am not able to navigate from MasterPage.xaml to Slide_show.xaml on a button click.

```
 public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{ public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);


    }
  private void Play_C(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Slide_show obj=new Slide_show();
        //obj.MainPage_Loaded(sender,e);
        try
        {
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Slide_show.xaml",UriKind.Relative));

        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("unable to show");
        }
    }
```

the xaml file is

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"  
x:Class="photoViewer.MainPage"

xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"

xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Portrait"  
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <Button Content="Play" Grid.Row="1" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,696,170,0" Name="button5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="114" Background="Transparent"   Click="Play_C"/>


</Grid>
```

The Slide_show.xaml.cs file is

```
public class Slide_show : PhoneApplicationPage
{
 public Slide_show()
    {
        //InitializeComponent();

       Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 3 issues.

The first is that when navigating to a page with a `Relative` Uri you should start the uri with a `/`. e.g:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Slide_Show.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

The second is that `Slide_show.xaml.cs` is no defined as a partial class. In this case you are essentially defining 2 classes with the same name as a partial class will be generated based on the xaml. (Or rather the generated)

Thirdly, you are disabling the call to `InitializeComponent()`. Without this the page wouldn't be constructed correctly. (Assuming you'd addressed the last 2 issues.)

I'm guessing that you added the new page ("Slide_Show"). You then removed the partial keyword (for whatever reason) and then commented out the now invalid call to InitializeComponent.
Put back the code you deleted / commented out. The template puts it there for a reason.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. U r rite that i had the code but then commented it..Coz always had an error saying that InitializeComponent() is not found in current context

Answer (score 2):

I think one "/" is missing in your Uri.
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Slide_show.xaml",UriKind.Relative));
nor try..

Answer (score 0):

Is an exception getting caught in your try/catch or is it just not displaying? If there is an exception what is it?

Comment: I t goes to the debugger break in App.xaml.cs and shows navigation failed..                                                       private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // A navigation has failed; break into the debugger
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            }
        }

Comment: Can you get the actual exception from e.Exception?

Comment: How to get that? I tried e1.getBaseException(); .. but nothing happennd